# Which is the best standard sql query to solve maximum in a subgroup

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have to do an exam and even if with a dbms (MySQL to be more accurate) the queries works. I'm asking myself if is formally right and which form is more formally correct in the following problem assuming a table as follow:

```sql
create table T(
    k integer primary key not null autoincrement,
    camp1 integer not null,
    camp2 integer not null);
```

Find the row for each value of camp2 that has the camp3 that is the maximum value for the subset:
Which solution is correct and if both of them are correct which is formally the best?

```sql
select * from T group by camp2 having camp3 = max(camp3);
```

or

```sql
select * from T b group by camp2 having camp3 = (select max(camp3) from T where T.camp2 = b.camp2);
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the queries? Which one you think is correct?

Comment: This question has been answered many times on Stack Overflow. I added the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag, so you can click on that and see many answers.

Comment: There is no `camp3` in your table. Also it's `auto_increment` not `autoincrement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.camp3 = (select max(t2.camp3) from t t2 where t2.camp2 = t.camp2);
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(camp2, camp3)`.

Your queries should generate syntax errors because they are malformed SQL statements -- the use of `select *` with `group by` is generally not allowed.  In particular, all expressions in the `select` of an aggregation query should either be expressions on the `group by` keys or they should be arguments to aggregation functions.

Although the above has the best performance (with the right index!) over a wide range of databases, many people prefer `row_number()` instead:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by camp2 order by camp3 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This also has good performance.  And in more modern massively parallel databases (eg. Redshift, BigQuery, PrestoDB) it is likely to have better performance.

Comment: is it standard sql?

Comment: @P.Carlino . . . .yes.  Your queries are not.